# password reset link not working in drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, password-recovery

When the user gets a user password reset link like this password reset like this http://digitalsuite.unitedway.org/user/reset/3/1356108765/5ff18af572734c897f4d7a2946983a87

it doesnt automatically log them in , they get no message, just goes to the login screen right away. 
Where is this coded so I can debug what is happening?
thanks
Diana

Answer (score 2):

When trying to figure out where to start debugging in Drupal, it generally helps to take a look at the hook_menu implementation that defines the page in question. Hook_menu "…enables modules to register paths in order to define how URL requests are handled."

In this case, the user module's [user_menu function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_menu/6), is [defined in the user.module file](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/01567a63437da3a09afee312ce5b16a5acdeaf16:/core/modules/user/user.module#l1092).

```
$items['user/reset/%/%/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Reset password',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('user_pass_reset', 2, 3, 4),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
);
```

Notice that 'page arguments' points to 'user_pass_reset', which is located in the [user.pages.inc file](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/01567a63437da3a09afee312ce5b16a5acdeaf16:/core/modules/user/user.pages.inc#l98). That would be a good place to start debugging.

Comment: Hi thanks, I found out the problem was the required login module, when I disabled this the password reset works fine.